How to get function keys working on a Yunzii keyboard?
I have a Yunzii B705 keyboard. It has a row of multimedia keys that double as the function keys. Neither the multimedia nor function keys can work. I don't care about using the multimedia functions, as that is something I rarely use, but need to use function keys daily. I tried many key combinations, but cannot get any key, from F1 to F12 to work.

I tried FN+F1.
I tried FN+1.
I tried FN+CAPS, then F1.
I tried FN FN, twice, long hold.

How can I get these function keys working?

Perhaps there's a flashing tool or functionality to enable "legacy" buttons?

@SirMuffington How would one find that?

have you tried contacting their support or looking at their website?

Whare are you trying to use it?  If on linux or *BSD, then it is not supported from manufacturer.  The manufacturer specifies that it  is compatible with:  The keyboard is compatible with Mac OS, iOS, Windows, and Android operating systems. FN+Q enters the Android system. Fn+W for Windows, Fn+E for Mac.

Running xev, Linux clearly can "hear" the keys are being typed. Is there a way to edit .Xdefaults or .Xresources to interpret these key-presses as function keys?

On the B705, double tapping Fn (just quickly, no long hold) should toggle Fn-lock, so if F1 currently decreases brightness, double tap Fn to make F1 (no modifiers) enter F1 verbatim instead, and vice versa.
If F1 does neither, something might be messed-up with your keyboard configuration. AFAIK, there is no software for this model to reflash or otherwise fix this, but you can try the following:

Press and hold Fn+Esc for 5 seconds, then release both. The device resets.
Once it's done, press and hold Fn+W. Lacking a dedicated Unix/Linux mode, Windows mode is the closest you can get, and this activates it.

Then again, check/verify that pressing F1 (no modifiers, no Fn-lock) or Fn+F1 (with Fn-lock) indeed enters F1.
Should it still fail to do so, your system might expect other function key keycodes than the B705 is able to produce. However, since you do see something in xev, there's a good chance you can adapt your X configuration accordingly:

In an X terminal, enter xmodmap -pke | grep -Ee '= F[0-9]{1,2}' to see the function keys part of your X server's current keycode to keysym mappings. The first keysym, or column, after each '=' denotes the base mapping of the respective keycode without modifiers, whilst any trailing columns denote mappings of that keycode when combined with various (combinations of) modifiers.
Also in an X terminal, note the "keycode" (an integer from 8 through 255) in the output of xev that's generated by pressing F1 on the B705.
Teach your X server that keycode is meant to represent the F1 keysym. Unfortunately, the required proceeding varies a lot, depending on the particular system or distro.

Traditional X input mappings would simply let you adjust the keycode in the corresponding output line of step 1 and feed it back into the X server's input mappings by xmodmap -e '<adjusted mapping line>' key by key, or just generate an entire keymap file by xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap and then edit the latter.
With xkb though, things have gotten more abstract and sophisticated. For a starter, see e. g. this general guide or this answer for a keyboard specific solution.
